# Get amount of pixels which are not visible of first not fully visible element in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView with elements, I need to get an amount of pixels which are not visible of a first not fully visible element, how do I do that?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question more because i am not getting what you want to say.

Comment: I need amount of pixels which are not visible to the user (width of the invisible part) not the color.

Comment: Add some code. Are you saying the item is wider than the screen and you want to know the difference? Just get the width of the item and the width of the screen and subtract them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, basically in such situations method `getLocalVisibleRect` allows to do that I want:

```
Rect r = new Rect();
getChildAt(0).getLocalVisibleRect(r);
if (getChildAt(0).getWidth() >= r.right - r.left) { //Check if element is not fully visible, calculation of the invisible part.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pixel from the view like this:

```
ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)v);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
```

Now you can get each channel with:

```
int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
```

The Color functions return the value in each channel. So all you have to do is check if Red is 255 and green and blue are 0, than set the textView text to "it is red". Just pay attention that saying that something is red is not simply that the red channel is the greater than zero. 'Cos 255-Green and 255-Red is yellow, of course.
You can also just compare the pixel to different color.
for example:

```
if(pixel == Color.MAGENTA){
   textView.setText("It is Magenta");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I need amount of pixels which are not visible to the user (width of the invisible part) not the color.